# XSL отобразить произвольное количество узлов

Tags: xslt

Есть xml такого вида:

```xml
<СуммаЗаМесяц>
    <Месяц>11</Месяц>
    <Год>2011</Год>
    <Выплат>2</Выплат>
    <Выплата>
        <Вид>Текст</Вид>
        <Сумма>10</Сумма>
    </Выплата>
    <Выплата>
        <Вид>Текст</Вид>
        <Сумма>15</Сумма>
    </Выплата>
</СуммаЗаМесяц>
<СуммаЗаМесяц>
    <Месяц>12</Месяц>
    <Год>2011</Год>
    <Выплат>2</Выплат>
    <Выплата>
        <Вид>Текст</Вид>
        <Сумма>10</Сумма>
    </Выплаты>
    <Выплата>
        <Вид>Текст</Вид>
        <Сумма>15</Сумма>
    </Выплаты>
</СуммаЗаМесяц>
```

Все это надо выводить в виде HTML-таблицы, построчно, в два столбца. Количество узлов "*СуммаЗаМесяц*" и "*Выплата*" может быть произвольным.
Подскажите, как сделать вывод всех этих узлов, если их число может изменяться и они имеют одинаковые имена?

Comment: А в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Понимаю, вопрос возможно с моей стороны выглядит глупым, но я в xsl новичок... Не могу понять как мне реализовать вывод одноименных узлов, если их количество в запросе может изменяться. При помощи каких элементов этого можно достичь.

Comment: а вам именно xslt нужен, или подойдет другой способ (например, XElement), который позволяет получить результат?

Comment: Нужен именно xslt шаблон

Comment: а в какую таблицу выводится? если надо получить html-таблицу (т.е. теги table, tr, td) -- это одно, а если выводится в контролы UI - другое.

Comment: Выводиться в html через table,td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'> 
    <xsl:output method='html' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes' /> 
    <xsl:template match='/'> 
    <table>             
        <xsl:for-each select='//Выплата'>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select='Вид' /></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select='Сумма' /></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>             
    </table>
    </xsl:template> 
    <!-- правила для вывода тегов -->
    <xsl:template match='Сумма'><xsl:value-of select='.' /></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match='Вид'><xsl:value-of select='.' /></xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

для выполнения xslt в C#:

```
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
// ...
static string Transform(string xslt, string xml) {      
    var t = new XslCompiledTransform();
    t.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xslt)));
    var x = new XmlDocument();
    x.LoadXml(xml);     
    var w = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    t.Transform(x.CreateNavigator(), null, w);
    return w.ToString();
}
// ...
string xslt = ...;
string xml = ...; 
var r = Transform(xslt, xml);               
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

примерный формат результата

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`for-each`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp)

```
<table>
  <xsl:for-each select="//Выплата">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Вид" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Сумма" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
<table>
```

Comment: При использовании for-each, я столкнулся с такой проблемой: в таблице под узлом "СуммаЗаМесяц" #11 выводятся вперемешку "Выплаты" и из других узлов "СуммаЗаМесяц" #12 и т.д. Можно ли каким то образом сделать разграничение между узлами, чтобы не было такой путаницы? Т.е. было так "Месяц#11" - "Выплаты за месяц #11" |"Месяц#12" - "Выплаты за месяц#12"

Comment: @Kridshi Разумеется, можно. Вложите один цикл в другой :)

Comment: @Kridshi наверное лучше в вопрос добавить это условие, а также добавить каким должен быть результат (не html, а результат вывода html, т.е. сама таблица).